# how to get the number after '-' in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some strings in my table. They are like 1101-1, 1101-2, 1101-10, 1101-11 pulse, shock, abc, 1104-2, 1104-11, 2201-1, 2202-4. I tried to sort them like below:

```
1101-1
1101-2
1101-10
1101-11
1104-2
1104-11
2201-1
2202-4
abc
pulse
shock
```

But I can't get the sort correctly. Below is my codes:

```
select column from table
order by regexp_substr(column, '^\D*') nulls first,
         to_number(substr(regexp_substr(column, '\d+'),1,4)) asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort numbers as *numbers*:

- first the ones in front of the hyphen (line #16)
- then the ones after it (line #17),
- then the rest (line #18)

Mind the `to_number` function! Without it, you'll be sorting **strings**! and get the wrong result.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2  ( select '1101-1'  from dual union all
  3    select '1101-2'  from dual union all
  4    select '1101-10' from dual union all
  5    select '1101-11' from dual union all
  6    select 'pulse'   from dual union all
  7    select 'shock'   from dual union all
  8    select 'abc'     from dual union all
  9    select '1104-2'  from dual union all
 10    select '1104-11' from dual union all
 11    select '2201-1'  from dual union all
 12    select '2202-4'  from dual
 13  )
 14  select col
 15  from test
 16  order by to_number(regexp_substr(col, '^\d+')),
 17           to_number(regexp_substr(col, '\d+$')),
 18           col;

COL
-------
1101-1
1101-2
1101-10
1101-11
1104-2
1104-11
2201-1
2202-4
abc
pulse
shock

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you! You are right. I will be sorting strings instead fo number without to_number

Answer (score 0):

For your examples, this should do:

```
order by regexp_substr(column, '^[^-]+'), -- everything before the hyphen
         len(column),
         column
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the number after '-' specifically:

```
with ttt (col) as (
    select cast(column_value as varchar2(10)) as second_str
    from   table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll
           ( '1101-1'
           , '1101-2'
           , '1101-10'
           , '1101-11'
           , '1104-2'
           , '1104-11'
           , '2201-1'
           , '2202-4'
           , 'abc'
           , 'pulse'
           , 'shock'
           ))
    )
select col
     , regexp_substr(col, '(^\d+-)(\d+)', 1, 1, '', 2)
from   ttt;
```

```
COL        SECOND_STR
---------- ----------
1101-1     1
2201-1     1
1101-10    10
1101-11    11
1104-11    11
1101-2     2
1104-2     2
2202-4     4
abc        
pulse      
shock      

11 rows selected
```

This treats the text string as two values, `(^\d+-)` followed by `(\d+)`, and takes the second substring (the final '2' parameter). As only positional parameters are allowed for built-in SQL functions, you also have to specify occurrence (1) and match param (null, as we don't care about case etc).